# When a key expires, set_response_callback is not calling the callback method

Tags: python, redis, callback

I am trying to get a callback, which would trigger when a key expires, to work as I want it to, and that is:

- When a key expires, I need the callback method to be called with the expired key as argument;
- This callback has to be asynchronous.

I'm working with:

- Ubuntu
- Redis 4.0.9
- Python 3.6.7 / redis.version = 3.0.1

Currently I'm using the **set_response_callback** method, as you can see in the code provided.

When I subscribe to Redis events, using **redis-cli**, the expiration keys are displayed correctly and in time:

```
$ redis-cli --csv psubscribe '__key*__:expired'

Reading messages... (press Ctrl-C to quit)
"psubscribe","__key*__:expired",1

"pmessage","__key*__:expired","__keyevent@0__:expired","key"
"pmessage","__key*__:expired","__keyevent@0__:expired","key"
```

But when I am setting a callback 'EXPIRE', as below:

```
r = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, charset="utf-8", db=0)

def __key_expired(arg):
    with open('test', 'a') as f:
       f.write('%s' % arg)

r.set_response_callback('EXPIRE', __key_expired)

r.set('key', 'value')
r.expire('key', SECONDS_TO_EXPIRE)

( ... )
```

The "__key_expired" callback is only called when the `r.expire('key', SECONDS_TO_EXPIRE)` is called and with a wrong argument.

I expect the argument to be "**key**" but I get "**1**".

**Question #1**:
Is there something wrong in the code? Or perhaps I am using wrong methods/arguments to make this use-case working?

**Question #2**:
I know that in JAVA it's possible to subscribe to a certain pattern, that is, for instance `__key*__:expired`. Can I do something like that in Python?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a Pub/Sub connection and subscribe to keyspace notifications (after enabling on the server) instead of using `set_response_callback()`.

`set_response_callback()` is meant for overriding the default callback of the redis-py client commands. The actual expiry event happens in Redis asynchronously, after the callback has been called.

Comment: but the Pub/Sub connection will need a python Thread in active waiting, won't it?

Comment: Implementation is up to you, but yeah, that makes sense :)